# Export a text file to MySQL in Talend

Tags: mysql, talend

So I have many files like this :

The first file :

```
 File1;
 Code;1971;1981;1991;2001;2011
 A;10;20;30;40;50
 B;12;22;32;89;95
 ...
 ...
```

The second file :

```
File2;
     Code;1971;1981;1991;2001;2011
     A;1500;1600;460;6000;8000
     B;6000;7000;8007;8009;9005
     ...
     ...
```

All Files have the exact same format.

I like to have a table in my database like this :

```
File   Code   Year   Value
File1  A      1971   10
File1  A      1981   20 
File1  A      1991   30
       .      .      .
       .      .      .
File2  A      1971   1500
File2  A      1981   1600 
File1  A      1991   460
  .     .      .      .
   .    .      .      .
File2  B      1971   .
File2  B      1981   .
  .     .      .      .
```

My idea is to creat for each file a t_map in wich we have the file as follow : 
[My solution with t_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKL7x.png)

The problem is that I have so many file like this, and my solution will take me a long time to finish it. Is there any better solution ?

Comment: can you change the layout of your files to a standard layout?  in other words put your column headings in row 1, then your row1 data in row 2, etc.  The type of file layout you are using is very unconventional, and instead of trying to program to it, I recommend you change to a conventional layout.  If you do that, the Talend solution becomes much simpler.

Answer (score -4):

I prefer using PHP to dump all data into MySQL...

```
Code;1971;1981;1991;2001;2011
A;10;20;30;40;50
B;12;22;32;89;95
```

after Open & Read file ($file), try this...

```
<?php 

function _T($a){return rtrim(trim($a));}
function _E($a,$b){return explode($a,$b);}
function _S($a,$b,$c){return str_replace($a,$b,$c);}
function _G($a,$b,$c){$d=strpos($a,$b);$e=substr($a,$d);$f=strpos($a,$c);return substr($e,0,($f-$d));}

$file='Code;1971;1981;1991;2001;2011
A;10;20;30;40;50
B;12;22;32;89;95';

$fC=_E('|',_S('Code;','|Code;',$file));
/*Useful with Multiple "Code;" in same file too*/
$fC2=($file).'|';
/* Add "|" to the last */

$fY=array();/*Year*/
$fA=array();/*A*/
$fB=array();/*B*/
$dB=array();/* For Database */
foreach($fC as $fR){
/* Get Year; */
$gY=_E(';',_S('Code;','',_G(_T($fR),'Code;','A;')));
$c=0;foreach($gY as $yR){if(!empty($yR)){/*echo _T($yR).'<br>';*/$fY[$c++]=_T($yR);}}
/* Get A */
$gA=_E(';',_S('A;','',_G(_T($fR),'A;','B;')));
$c=0;foreach($gA as $aR){if(!empty($aR)){/*echo _T($aR).'<br>';*/$fA[$c++]=_T($aR);}}
/* Get B */
$gB=_E(';',_S('B;','',_G(_T($fR),'B;','|')));
$c=0;foreach($gB as $bR){if(!empty($bR)){/*echo _T($bR).'<br>';*/$fB[$c++]=_T($bR);}}
if(empty($fB)){$gB=_E(';',_S('B;','',_G(_T($fC2),'B;','|')));
$c=0;foreach($gB as $bR){if(!empty($bR)){/*echo _T($bR).'<br>';*/$fB[$c++]=_T($bR);}}}
}

/* Show Result */
foreach($fY as $fK=>$fV){
echo $fK.':'.$fV.'='.$fA[$fK].'='.$fB[$fK].'<br>';
$dB[]=array('Year'=>$fV,'A'=>$fA[$fK],'B'=>$fB[$fK]);
}print_r($dB);

?>
```

Test yourself... :)

Comment: Hi there! One that I find helpful is to indent the code. A for-loop that is written in one line is very hard to read. Also, single character variable can be cryptic. Try to read your code in the OP perspective. The most he can do is copy and paste it.

Comment: " A for-loop that is written in one line is very hard to use. "
Not very hard... We just need to Get content inside A; -to- B;

Comment: "Is there any better solution ?" <--- am I did anything wrong here..? Or just see & read my code without test.? :|